# How to get the declared variable

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, xna-4.0, game-development

**When i try to print the variable from another class, it prints the undeclared variable, so only 0.**

Here is an example:

```
public class Player
{

Enemy enemy;

public void Initialize(){
enemy = new Enemy();
}

public void Update()
{
Console.WriteLine(enemy.Rectangle);
}

}

public class Enemy()
{

public Rectangle Rectangle;

public void Update()
{
Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can help you

```
public class Player
{

        Enemy enemy;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            enemy = new Enemy();
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            enemy.Update();
            Console.WriteLine(enemy.Rectangle);
        }

    }

    public class Enemy
    {

        public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rectangle;

        public void Update()
        {
            Rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(5, 10, 10, 10);
        }

}
```

Main:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.Initialize();
p.Update();
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Now it says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." At the line where i declared the rectangle.

Comment: So I called the  `update` of the `Enemy` class in the `update` of the `player`

Comment: @Alex The difference in value is maybe `Position` or `Texture` have `NULL` value.Can you check  `Position` and `Texture`?

Comment: So, when i call the update from the main class and print the texture and position from the enemy class,
everything prints out normally.  https://imgur.com/a/MD0abEo